# how to dockerize mozilla pdf.js application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

am trying to dockerize mozilla pdf.js repo but am facing permission issues with glup.
here is my Dockerfile & docker-compose :

```
# # Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:18

# Create a new user and group
RUN groupadd -r app && useradd -r -g app -G node -m -s /bin/bash app

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Assign ownership of the working directory to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app /app

# Copy the local project into the container
COPY . /app

# Switch to the app user
USER app

# Install Gulp globally
RUN npm install gulp-cli
RUN npm install gulp
# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install


# Make port 8888 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8888

# Run the application when the container launches
CMD ["gulp", "server"]
```

```
version: '3'
services:
  pdfjs:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

when i run docker-compose up --build , i get the below error:
6.703 npm ERR! code EACCES
6.703 npm ERR! syscall mkdir
6.703 npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli
6.703 npm ERR! errno -13
6.705 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli'
6.705 npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli'] {
6.705 npm ERR!   errno: -13,
6.705 npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
6.705 npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
6.705 npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli'
6.705 npm ERR! }

tried a lot of approach but nothing work.

i did some changes to my Dockerfile and now the application is been build without any issue. However, the result not what i was expecting. When i try to access http://localhost:8888/web/viewer.html i don't see anything in the page. Am suppose to view the example pdf file in web. Here is my updated Dockerfile:
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["gulp", "server"]

EXPOSE 8888

Comment: Your `app` user doesn't have access to modify data in the `/usr/local` directory. Try removing `USER app` in your Dockerfile. Or moving it down until after the Gulp install.

Answer (score 0):

The Dockerfile `COPY` directive normally makes the files it adds owned by the root user, even if the current `USER` is something else.

One common setup is to do all of the package setup and installation as root, and change to a different `USER` only at the end of the Dockerfile where you also specify the `CMD`.  Do not `chown` anything in the image to the non-root user: the code will be owned by root and world-readable but not world-writable, which avoids the possibility of accidentally overwriting it.

```bash
FROM node:18
RUN useradd -r app
WORKDIR /app

# here: do not chown the directory; do not switch USER yet

COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install gulp-cli
RUN npm install gulp
RUN npm install

# here: switch USER now
USER app

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["gulp", "server"]
```

Make sure to also delete the `volumes:` block in the Compose file that overwrites the image's `/app` directory.  To the extent that you're trying to work out file permissions in the image, overwriting that with a bind mount will hide all of this; there are potential compatibility problems around the `node_modules:` directory; and fundamentally you just won't be running anything in the image you've created.